# How to trigger privacy impact assessment if processing_activity.special_category_info_available == true in ServiceNow

Tags: javascript, privacy, business-rules, attestations

In our project, entities are not procesisng activities yet, thus we need to do a screening assessment first to get a more complete register of processing activities. I am very new using ServiceNow but have some experience wriitng js.
We want to trigger the impact assessment based on certain values for metric definitions or attributes of the newly created processing activity.

I rhoughly have something like this (triggered when processing activity with special category data is created):

```js
(function executeRule(current) {

    // Add your code here
    if (current.isSpecialCategory == true){

        var assessment = new GlideRecord('data_impact_assessment');
        assessment.initialize();
        assessment.processing_activity = current.sys_id; 
        
    }
})
```

I was looking for something like a `createImpactAssessment(processing activity)` method I could call instead of the line `new GlideRecord()`. Does anyone know if such a api exists or do you know another more efficient way to do this?